# UN MARSHALING XML to JAVA object for Restful Service using JAXRS

Tags: java, xml, rest, jax-rs, unmarshalling

I am trying to achieve BOOLEAN return (true/false) based on XML file upload by user. For instance, I have a element direction which indicates type of data it contains. So i am interested in un marshaling the data and return boolean.

Step 1: Interested in POST method and would be testing using [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) chrome app.

Step 2: Contents object to hold everything for un marshaling and marshaling

package validator.service;

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

// Created the Contents object to hold everything for un marshaling and marshaling

@XmlRootElement( name = "contents" )
public class Contents
{
    @XmlElement
    String portalarea;

    @XmlElement
    String portalsubarea;

    @XmlElement
    String direction;

    public String getportalarea()
    {
        return portalarea;
    }

    public String getportalsubarea()
    {
        return portalsubarea;
    }

    public String getdirection()
    {
        return direction;
    }

}
```

Step 3: Have Validation Class for receiving the Request and un marshal the XML to return boolean.

```
package validatorService;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

@Path ("/valid")
public class ValidatorService
{
    boolean n_value = false;
    boolean r_value = false;

    @POST
    @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
    @Consumes( "application/xml" )
    public String validate( String xmlContent )
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try
        {
            if ( xmlContent != null )
            {
                if ( xmlContent.startsWith( "https" ) )
                {
                    HttpGet xmlGet = new HttpGet( xmlContent );

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( xmlGet );
                    int responseStatus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    // String responseMessage = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

                    if ( responseStatus == 200 )
                    {
                        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream inStream = responseEntity.getContent();

                        Contents direction = unmarshalingContent( inStream, xmlContent );

                        if ( direction.equals( "N" ) )
                        {
                            n_value = true;


                        }
                        else if ( direction.equals( "R" ) )
                        {
                            r_value = true;


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println( "Response Error : " + responseStatus ); // Should be
                                                                                    // handled
                                                                                    // properly
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println( " 'https' Format Error" ); // Should be handled properly
                }

                return "success";
            }

        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println( " Error caught at catch " + e ); // Should be handled properly for
                                                                 // all exception
        }
        finally
        {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Contents unmarshalingContent( InputStream inputStream, String resourceClass ) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println( " welcome " );

        if ( resourceClass == "xmlContent" )
        {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.bar" );
            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

            XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLStreamReader xReader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader( inputStream );

            JAXBElement<Contents> jaxBElement = (JAXBElement<Contents>) u.unmarshal( xReader, Contents.class );

            Contents portalArea = (Contents) jaxBElement.getValue();
            Contents portalSubarea = (Contents) jaxBElement.getValue();
            Contents direction = (Contents) jaxBElement.getValue();

            return direction;
        }
        throw new Exception( "Invalid resource request" );

    }
}
```

I am new to RESTful Service and i read few documents and based on instructions i am trying to achieve the given task. So any help, corrections, guidance, code is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be much simpler. You don't need to do XML to Java object conversion by hand. JAX-RS providers are doing that automatically.

```
@POST
@Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
@Consumes( "application/xml" )
public Response validate(Contents con){ //con will be initialized by JAX-RS
  //validate your XML converted to object con
  boolean validation_ok = ...
  if(validation_ok){
     return Response.ok("true").build();
  }else{
     return Response.ok("false").build();
  }
}
```